# schema check error:element must be declared

Tags: xml, schema

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<teaching-plan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="teaching-plan.xsd">
    <course id="1">
        <course-name>
            大学英语
        </course-name>
        <class-hour>
            36
        </class-hour>
        <exam-form>
            考试
        </exam-form>
    </course>
    <course id="2">
        <course-name>
            高等数学
        </course-name>
        <class-hour>
            70
        </class-hour>
        <exam-form>
            考试
        </exam-form>
    </course>
    <course id="3">
        <course-name>
            计算机应用基础
        </course-name>
        <class-hour>
            108
        </class-hour>
        <exam-form>
            上机考试
        </exam-form>
    </course>
</teaching-plan>
```

and this is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <element name="teaching-plan">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="course" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="100">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="course-name" type="string"></element>
                            <element name="class-hour" >
                                <simpleType>
                                    <restriction base="integer">
                                        <minInclusive value="2"></minInclusive>
                                        <maxInclusive value="5"></maxInclusive>
                                    </restriction>
                                </simpleType>
                            </element>
                            <element name="exam-form" type="string"></element>
                        </sequence>
                        <attribute name="id" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

the idea editor keeps telling me that element teaching-plan must be declared, but i did declared in the schema.
Could this be the editor problem or i missed something?
Just start to learn xml and schema, still has a lot of questions.
can any one tell me how to solve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get running the validation using Saxon from the command line:

```
Validation error on line 7 column 21 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "\n            36\n        " of element <class-hour> does not match
  the required simple type. Value "36" contravenes the maxInclusive facet "5" of the type of
  element class-hour
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 18 column 21 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "\n            70\n        " of element <class-hour> does not match
  the required simple type. Value "70" contravenes the maxInclusive facet "5" of the type of
  element class-hour
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 29 column 21 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "\n            108\n        " of element <class-hour> does not match
  the required simple type. Value "108" contravenes the maxInclusive facet "5" of the type
  of element class-hour
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 36 column 17 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Three validation errors were reported. First error: The content "\n           
  36\n        " of element <class-hour> does not match the required simple type. Value "36"
  contravenes the maxInclusive facet "5" of the type of element class-hour
Validation complete: errors found
```

What this tells us is that there's nothing basically wrong with your schema. The instance isn't valid against the schema, but that's fine.

This doesn't directly help you know what's going wrong with your attempts to run the validation - except that it tells you it's something to do with the way you are running things, it's not something fundamentally wrong with your code.

I would make one suggestion about your schema: is the maxOccurs="100" there because there really is a fundamental limit on how many courses there can be, or is it there because you thought having a limit seemed like a good idea? I would suggest that firstly, it's better to have no limit unless you really need one, and secondly, large values of maxOccurs can be very expensive to evaluate; schema validators that construct simple finite state automata to do the validation will end up with a very large number of states.